# rgl observer3d: how to center view on selected point?

Tags: r, rgl

I've been trying, with little success so far, to center the rgl observer on a point previously selected with identify3d.
This is a (not) working example:

```
library(rgl)  
if (interactive()) {  
      x <- rnorm(1000)  
      y <- rnorm(1000)  
      z <- rnorm(1000)  
      open3d()  
      points3d(x, y, z)  
      while(interactive()) {   
        keep <- identify3d(x, y, z, n=1, plot=F)  
        if (!is.null(keep)) {  
          observer3d(x[keep],  
                     y[keep],  
                     par3d("observer")[3])   
        }  
      }  
    }
```

I'm able to move the observer but I can't quite figure out how to transform my coordinates so the selected point appear at the center of my view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you don't want the observer to be at a particular point, you want to translate the scene so that point is at the center of the view.  You do this by multiplying the `par3d("userMatrix")` value
by `translationMatrix(x, y, z)` where the args are chosen to move
the point to the middle.

This is fairly easy to do if you don't also want to allow rotations or other user changes between translations.  If you do, then you need 
to read `par3d("userMatrix")` just before each change, and
undo the previous translation before applying the new one.

For example,

```
library(rgl)
if (interactive()) {  
  x <- rnorm(10)  
  y <- rnorm(10)  
  z <- rnorm(10)  
  open3d() 
  text3d(x, y, z, seq_along(x)) 
  center <- c(0.5, 0.5) %*% matrix(par3d("bbox"), 2, 3) 
  prev <- c(0, 0, 0)  # initially, no translation
  while(interactive()) {   
    keep <- identify3d(x, y, z, n=1, plot=F)  
    pt <- c(x[keep], y[keep], z[keep])
    xlat <- center - pt  # undo automatic centering and center on the point
    userMatrix <- par3d("userMatrix")
    par3d(userMatrix = userMatrix %*% t(translationMatrix(xlat[1] - prev[1], 
                                                          xlat[2] - prev[2], 
                                                          xlat[3] - prev[3])))
    prev <- xlat
    }  
  }
```

This might not work properly if you are also doing scaling; see the `?par3d` help topic for the full sequence of transformations that `rgl` does when rendering a scene.